# custom filters score query for elasticsearch giving parsing error

Tags: elasticsearch

it's telling me there's No query registered for [custom_filters_score]];

here's my code in basic form:

```
  "query": {
    "custom_filters_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filters": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "salesrank"
            }
          }
          ,"script": "1 / doc['salesrank'].value"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

the only thing i've noticed that works is to put another query after the first 'query' and before 'custom_filters_score'. this then leaves me with two queries - not sure what to do with them both however, and the documentation does not indicate this. :(

i also have to get rid of the 'filters' array and only use a 'filter' object. so, the only thing i've found to work is something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}, 
    "custom_filters_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "salesrank"
        }
         ,"script": "1 / doc['salesrank'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the elasticsearch documentation: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-custom-filters-score-query.html, the "custom_filters_score" was deprecated.  The correct way to do it is to replace it with "function_score"

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "1 / doc['salesrank'].value"
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "salesrank"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: no, i believe you're looking at the 'score_mode' element which is a different thing than 'script'. 'script' is the same as 'boost' in the referenced example.

Comment: modified my answer to show the correct way to do it

Comment: geez i guess i need to rtfm a bit more. thanks @alcanzar